# How do i smooth the CornerRadius of WindowChrome?

Tags: c#, wpf, window-chrome

I create simple window use WindowChrome. When i use a CornerRadius, the corners of the window become a pixel ladder. How do i smooth it?

```
<WindowChrome.WindowChrome>
    <WindowChrome CornerRadius="15" GlassFrameThickness="0" CaptionHeight="20"></WindowChrome>
</WindowChrome.WindowChrome>
```

[image: example]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Unfortunately, you can't smooth it using the `WindowChrome` `CornerRadius` property.

You can achieve the same effect, but it requires a lot more work.

You have provide a custom style/control template, and add the corner radius on a root `Border`. Then you need to make sure to clip the border's contents to your corner radius.

I have an attached behavior that I use to do the clipping.

You get a really nice result, but it's much more work.

Comment: That would work but unfortunately it would require AllowTransparency which also requires WindowStyle.None and that way you'll lose the native animations for closing and minimizing which is ugly.